# clang_complete error: unknown argument: '--std=c++0x'

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++, clang-complete

clang++ version: 2.9
vim version: 7.3

I write my `.clang_comple`

```
--std=c++0x
```

with follow source code `test.cc`:

```
int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

And the clang_complete shows

```
test.cc|| unknown argument: '--std=c++0x'
```

in the quickfix list.

I try to add the option with

```
set g:clang_user_options="--std=c++0x"
```

the problem is still there.

Tried to trace some code of clang_complete, but still can not solve that problem. All other options can be processed correctly, but not `--std=c++0x` Do I miss anything? or made something wrong?

Comment: Despite adding `c++0x` tag it is turning as `c++11`. Huh ...

Comment: @Mahesh: c++11 is the standard accepted from the c++0x draft (http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't `--std=c++0x` but `-std=c++0x` according to the [docs](http://libcxx.llvm.org/). Try it but I have never used clang though.

From docs :

> To use with clang you can:
>
> - `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp`
> - `clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

In .vimrc,  I usually use the following config:

```
let g:clang_user_options='-std=c++0x -x c++' 
map <F2>  :call g:ClangUpdateQuickFix()<CR>
```

Thus, I can press  to compile the *.cpp files and

then use quickfix window to debug errors.